# Path independence of complex functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How do i show that $\int e^{-2z}dz$ is independent of the path C joining the points $1-\pi i$ and $2+3\pi i$. Only thing i was able to do was determine the value of this definite integral. Am to to take C to be some arbitary paths like parabolas and straight lines and show that the values are equal? (although that apprach seems stupid.)

Comment: Have you considered using the fundamental theorem of calculus? Or Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @KennyWong Somehow i suspect Cauchy Riemann equations, but i am not quite sure what using it would infer.

Comment: But what about the fundamental theorem of calculus? Or alternatively, how about using Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @KennyWong If i draw two curves joining the two given points and since the given function is analytic then Cauchy theorem would infer that integration over the closed curve is 0. So, am i just to write these words or can i give some rigorous proof.

Comment: This **is** a rigorous proof, isn't it?

Comment: @KennyWong Please enlighten me, i think i can't see the essence of it

Comment: @KennyWong I Mean if i were to draw any arbitary curve, what assures that it would give the same value in the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be two paths from $P_1$ to $P_2$ then $\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2^{-}$ is a closed path ($\gamma_2^{-}$ is the path $\gamma_2$ with the orientation reversed). If $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ (like your $e^{2z}$), by the [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem),
$$0=\int_{\gamma_1\cup \gamma_2^{-}} f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_1} f(z)dz-\int_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz$$
which implies that
$$\int_{\gamma_1} f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz,$$
that is the integral is independent of the path.

To compute the integral, note that $\frac{d}{dz}(e^{2z}/2)=e^{2z}$ and for any path $\gamma$ from $P_1$ to $P_2$,
$$\int_{\gamma} e^{2z}dz=\left [\frac{e^{2z}}{2}\right]_{1−\pi i}^ {2+3\pi i}=\frac{e^{4+6\pi i}-e^{2−2\pi i}}{2}=\frac{e^{4}-e^{2}}{2}.$$

Comment: Not sure why you bring Cauchy's theorem into it.

Comment: @zhw Cauchy's theorem implies a more general statement which holds for the particular case of $e^{2z}$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(z)=e^{2z}$ has a primitive, namely $F(z)=\frac12e^{2z}$. Therefore, if $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is *any* path joining $1-\pi i$ to $2+3\pi i$, then$$\int_\gamma e^{2z}\,\mathrm dz=F(2+3\pi i)-F(1-\pi i)=\frac{e^4-e^2}2.$$